# Linux: Setting range between 0-8 hours if less or greater than this then re-enter valid number (clock-in work)

Tags: bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash

work="GAP"
a="Monday"
b="Tuesday"
c="Wednesday"
d="Thursday"
e="Friday"

echo "How many hours you worked of $a"
    read $a
echo "How many hours you worked of $b"
    read $b
echo "How many hours you worked of $c"
    read $c
echo "How many hours you worked of $d"
    read $d
echo "How many hours you worked of $e"
    read $e

f=15

g=$((( $a + $b + $c + $d + $e ) * 15 ))

echo "You've earned $g dollars at $work."
```

Trying to set range for hours between 0-8 & if user enters a number less or greater than the range then they have re-enter valid number.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I don't know to set a range. I just started to learn how use this.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
work="GAP"
f=15
days=("Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday")

for d in "${days[@]}"; do
    while true; do
        read -p "How many hours did you work on $d: " h
        if [[ $h =~ ^[0-8]$ ]]; then
            break
        else
            echo "Please input integer between 0 and 8, inclusive."
        fi
    done
    (( sum += h ))
done

g=$(( sum * f ))
echo "You've earned $g dollars at $work."
```

- It will be convenient to set the days of the week in an array.
- Then you can iterate over the days with the loop: `for d in "${days[@]}" ..`.
- The test `[[ $h =~ ^[0-8]$ ]]` returns `true` if and only if you enter
  0, 1, 2, .. or 8. Otherwise it repeats the `while` loop until a proper
  value is input.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for responding late & yeah it really helped out but I just wanted to ask something about it so I can get a better understanding of it. Like why did you use (@)  for the d in days. Also why is ^[0-8]$ set up in this way.

Comment: @CristobalArevalo Thank you for the response. 
`for d in "${days[@]}"` is equivalent to `for d in ("Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday")` and we do not
even have to assign the array variable. It may be a matter of taste.
As for the condition `[[ $h =~ ^[0-8]$ ]]` it returns true if and only if a user inputs a number between 0 and 8.
The notation `^[0-8]$` is called a `regular expresion`. `^` matches a start of the string, `[0-8]` matches a number
between 0 and 8, and `$` matches an end of the string. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I really appreciate it.